# Rのlintr パッケージがインストールできない理由

Tags: r

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]RStudioで、lintrパッケージをダウンロードしようとしていますが、うまくいきません。
下記のようなエラーが出てしまうそうです。対処法がありましたらご教示いただければ幸いです。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 画像を確認しましたが、具体的なエラー内容が見切れているように思えます。おそらくキャプチャしている部分の後にもエラーメッセージが出ていると思うので、そちらも出してもらえると皆さんが対応しやすくなると思います

Comment: C コンパイラが clang に設定されていて、clang には `-fopenmp` オプションがないためエラーになっています。なので、`$HOME/.R/Makevars` ファイルに `CC = gcc` を追加すればコンパイル時のエラーは回避できる様に思えます(gcc には `-fopenmp` オプションがあります)。

Comment: kazutanさんありがとうございます。キャプチャ追加しました。

metropolisさん、ありがとうございます。

＞$HOME/.R/Makevars ファイルに CC = gcc を追加すればコンパイル時のエラーは回避できる様に思えます(gcc には -fopenmp オプションがあります)。
というのはどういうことでしょうか？もう少し詳しくおしえていただいてもよいですか？